# Smallest rpm based linux possible?

Tags: linux, package-management, packages, rpm

Considering Linux distributions that are based on RPM. How can we have the smallest possible of these Linuxes in size with minimum number of packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora with the [appliance kickstart](https://fedorahosted.org/spin-kickstarts/browser/fedora-aos.ks) will give you a tiny base to build upon. Be sure to edit the repos before using though.

Comment: could you give some information about the link you have given? how can it help me?

Comment: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart

Comment: thanks, but can you help me on another thing? on the Kickstart wiki page in chapter 3 it is written : "Refer to the repodata/*comps.xml file on the first CD-ROM for a list of groups[ of packages]."
but I didn't find the file in my fedora 12 DVD (X86-64). where could I find that list?

Comment: It (or another file that ends in `comps.xml` or `comps.xml.gz`) should be found in `repodata/`.

Comment: there is another question came to my mind. in the first link, there is the aos.ks file that seems to satisfy my need. but I have a question about the file: when the scripts are defining the packages to be installed we see first of all it used the --nobase option means no base package group should be installed then it begins to specify the packages like kernel and bash individually.It is ok until now but I see after those specification it comes with removing some packages.as i read i think we remove packages when we dont want them from a group.but there was no group specified,even base ignored!

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=rpmlive) looked promising:

> RPM Live Linux CD     RPM Live Linux CD
>   is a 120MB RedHat-based distribution
>   that runs completely from CD, fits
>   into around 80MB of RAM and is nearly
>   indistinguishable from a system
>   installed on a hard disk. Features
>   include hardware recognition at boot,
>   samba, dhcpd, name, xinetd, and SSH
>   servers, virtual terminals, PAM, etc.
>   Useful for dedicated servers, routers,
>   emergency systems, cluster nodes and
>   such, it does not contain an X11
>   Server.

Unfortunately, distrowatch reports RPM Live Linux CD (aka Basilisk Linux) as discontinued, and the site is down.

Your best bet is probably to download a RedHat/Fedora/CentOS *server* CD or live CD.  To minimize the number of packages, just don't install anything you don't absolutely need--such as X or any window managers (e.g., GNOME, KDE).

It's also worth noting that there are other, non-RPM-based distros, which have been stripped down to the bare minimum, yet still have some type of package manager.  [DSL](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) (available as a 50 MB live CD) is one of the better-known tiny linux distros, and I don't think you'll find much smaller unless you look at embedded projects such as [DD-WRT](http://dd-wrt.com).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Suse Studio](http://susestudio.com/) to build a tiny version of OpenSuse. The "Just Enough Operating System" base with all the defaults gives a downloadable iso file of 131MB.